# Determine if primary thread exits main function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

After exiting main function, c++ still cleans up some static, global, ... variables.
Inside destructors of those variable, how can I know if primary thread already exited main function?

Comment: Using standard C++ you can't. And neither should you. If you need to do that then I would argue that your design is flawed.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I am using VC++.

Comment: Are you wanting something like [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit)?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're seeing? (Which you've come up with this idea that could be an workaround for)

Comment: Thank @txtechhelp.
DeanSeo: I just want to clean up global variables in different approach if main function already exit to avoid some exception.